# Are there any open source OAuth 2 providers/servers for internal use

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider

I really want to host my own private OAuth 2 server/provider for internal use.  I would perfer an open source solution.

I can't seem to find any.  Either I am trying to do something dumb or I am not looking in the right place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[oauth2-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/)